# Why does the Samsung Galaxy S ignore the user-scalable meta tag?

Tags: android, html, mobile, galaxy

According to many sources, a meta tag like this is supposed to prevent the browser from letting the user zoom in and out of the page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

This works correctly on most mobile browsers, including iOS and most Android phones I've tested. However, the Samsung Galaxy S (Sprint Epic) does not respect it, instead allowing arbitrary zoom in/out by the user.

You can see this by visiting the Facebook "touch screen" page at http://touch.facebook.com/ - on most phones you can't zoom in that page, but on the Galaxy S you can.
I've also confirmed that the Galaxy S II correctly respects the meta tag, so this seems limited to the Galaxy S.

Is this just a bug in the Galaxy S's build of the browser? Is there any work-around that doesn't fail on other devices?

Comment: I had noticed that I can zoom in on more pages then other peoples phones. I like it this way to be honest.

Comment: I suspect it's not so much a bug as a feature.  What possible reason could you have for not letting people zoom in?

Comment: robertc: Some pages are already designed to be used like mobile apps on small screen with a touch-based interface. Allowing the user to zoom in and scroll around the page would then make it more confusing, reduce usability, and possibly interfere with how the page's user interface is supposed to work.

Comment: @robertc: I'm working on a page that is basically 1 long form. With scaling on the automatic zooming way in on each element makes the page very difficult to use. The only solution is making nice large elements in the mobile version and then turning off scaling. Basically, just because you can't think of a reason doesn't mean one doesn't exist :)

Comment: @JimboJonny Given the wide variety of screen sizes and the wide range in visual acuity of users on the internet, are you completely 100% sure that no-one who visits your page will want to make the text a little bigger in order to read it?

Comment: @robertc - 1) yes, I actually make it quite overly large, to the point were iOS devices don't even try to zoom on it any more, if they cannot read these words than they do not have eyesight capable of using the phone to get to the browser in the first place

Comment: @robertc - 2) when I make the text big enough to be of proper size for viewers, when android zooms in it literally zooms to where the height of 1 letter fills the entire vertical size of the screen and only 1 or 2 letters are visible at a time. You have to constantly zoom out to use it...and keeps doing that as you switch fields. It's absolutely horrid to use.

Comment: @robertc - 3) The idea that there is no situation where a custom built UI interaction could be better for usability than a certain default applied-to-everything UI interaction is quite frankly...crazy. And that's basically the stance you're taking: that there's no way that I've designed a form that would work better than android's auto-zooming default behavior. Not saying that to make you look stupid or anything...I'm sure you're not. But I'm saying it to maybe turn on a light bulb in your head that says "wow, ok, maybe I am being a bit over-zealous about this particular UI feature"

Comment: @JimboJonny I've used apps on my phone where the text was too small to read or buttons were too small to hit and yet zooming was disabled.  I'm not saying that great designers can't build apps that work for all users across all phones without scaling, but I will say that there are far less great designers than there are people who think they're great designers.  The light bulb went on in my head when I saw a man reading his Kindle with, quite literally, five words shown on each page.  I would never have believed there were people who needed text that size for reading if I hadn't seen it.

Comment: I confirm this "bug" on a Samsung A70. Has anyone managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

i use this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

and it works on my galaxy s

Comment: It doesn't work on my Samsung Galaxy Gio, which is running Android 2.3.6. Some people apparently had luck by adding `maximum-scale=1.0`, but that didn't work here either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but after some efforts I realized that is not about the phone or android version, it's about samsung explorer which is the default explorer.

Changing it to google chrome solved the problem for me. However I guess samsung should take care of this issue.